# Prove probability inequalities

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

With two conditions:

1. $Q(\theta)$ is uniquely minimized at $\theta_0$. That is, for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $\theta \notin B_\epsilon(\theta_0)$ implies $Q(\theta)-Q(\theta_0)\ge\delta$, where $B_\epsilon(\theta_0) = \left\{\theta \in \Omega; |\theta-\theta_0|<\epsilon\right\}$.
2. $\sup_{\theta \in \Omega}|Q_n(\theta)-Q(\theta)|\xrightarrow{p}0$, where $Q(\theta)$ is non-stochastic.

Let $\hat{\theta}= \arg\min Q_n(\theta)$.

$$
\begin{align}
0 & \le \mathbb{P}[\hat{\theta} \notin B_\epsilon(\theta_0)] \\
  & \le \mathbb{P}[Q(\hat{\theta}) - Q_n(\hat{\theta}) + Q_n(\hat{\theta}) - Q(\theta_0) \ge \delta] \tag{1}\\
  & \le \mathbb{P}[Q(\hat{\theta}) - Q_n(\hat{\theta}) + Q_n(\theta_0) - Q(\theta_0) \ge \delta]\tag{2}\\
  & \le \mathbb{P}[2\sup{|Q_n(\theta) - Q(\theta})|\ge\delta]  \tag{3}\\
  & \rightarrow 0
\end{align}
$$

I'm having trouble in deriving from $(1)$ to $(2)$ and from $(2)$ to $(3)$. Could you show me the details of $(1)$ to $(2)$ and $(2)$ to $(3)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going from (1) to (2) is just because $\hat{\theta}$ minimizes $Q_n(\theta)$, so $Q_n(\hat{\theta})\leq Q_n(\theta_0)$, so the left side of the inequality in (2) can only be larger than the left side of the inequality in (1).  Similarly, to go from (2) to (3), just observe that $Q(\hat{\theta})-Q_n(\hat{\theta})$ and $Q_n(\theta_0)-Q(\theta_0)$ are each less than or equal to $\sup_\theta |Q_n(\theta)-Q(\theta)|$.

Comment: From $(1)$ to $(2)$, I can see $Q_n(\hat{\theta})\leq Q_n(\theta_0)$, so $A=\{Q(\hat{\theta}) - Q_n(\hat{\theta}) + Q_n(\hat{\theta}) - Q(\theta_0) \ge \delta\} \subseteq \{Q(\hat{\theta}) - Q_n(\hat{\theta}) + Q_n(\theta_0) - Q(\theta_0) \ge \delta\}=B$, then the probability gets larger? I cannot justify why $A \subseteq B$.

Comment: If $X\leq Y$ then $X\geq \delta$ implies $Y\geq\delta$.